# Display duplicate lines in two columns of three

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sorting, uniq

I have a file with 3 columns, separated by commas, and I want to show the duplicate lines in two columns of three columns. This is an example:

```
SIP/Bear-out-000b8cf123,6669544,79541868
SIP/Bear-out-000b8cf456,6619259,6549449
SIP/Bear-out-000b8cf789,6619677,6593022
SIP/Bear-out-000b8cf987,6619259,6549449
SIP/Bear-out-000b8cf654,6669544,79541868
```

The columns duplicates are second and thrid. The first column is always different.

The method is en BASH.

Comment: **I want to show the duplicate lines in two columns of three columns** Can you add some examples?

Comment: What output do you want .. and what have you tried ?

Comment: I tried to sort the columns with a sort command and display duplicates with a uniq command. The problem is that first column is different, and not show de duplicate lines. All lines are similar, only change the numbers in the second and third column

Comment: The output should be: SIP/Bear-out-000b8cf123,6669544,79541868 and SIP/Bear-out-000b8cf456,6619259,6549449

Comment: Is it necessary for the first column to be in the result or are the second and third column sufficient?

Comment: Is necessary, This command shows me duplicates of the first column, but I can not show the second and third simultaneously: sort input | awk 'NR == 1 {p=$1; next} p == $1 { print $1 " is duplicated"} {p=$1}' FS=","

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `awk` command:

```
awk -F, '!($2 in a){a[$2]=$0; next} a[$2]{print a[$2]; delete a[$2]}' file
SIP/Bear-out-000b8cf456,6619259,6549449
SIP/Bear-out-000b8cf123,6669544,79541868
```